# Joining Two Tables but need to change value of Join

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, join

I need to join three tables.  Let's call them A, B and C.

Ideally I need to join A to B to C.

A contains an ID.  B Contains AID.  Easy to join.

However, C has a column where it looks like "00901".  I am to match that to Table B's AID which is "9".

Mind you, AID is an int while "00901" is varchar.

```
searchResults = db.A
    .Join(db.B, a => a.ID, b => b.AID, (a, b) => new { a = a, b = b })
    .Join(db.C, b => b.b.AID, c => Int32.Parse(c.cID.Substring(0, 3).TrimStart('0')), (b, c) => new { b = b, c = c })
    .Select(c => c. ).Distinct(); //this line is not complete
```

Thoughts as to how I can do this?

Comment: What is the required logic? Is it simply based on the 3rd character of the column in table B?

Comment: How do you match `9` to `"00901"`? Also what is `db`, please specify the target ORM (query provider) type.

Comment: Ivan that is what the question is.  Can i simply do a substring to it and modify the value?

Comment: juunas No, it can be say 9 = 00901 or 10 = 01001

Comment: Are you just looking for the first value to be contained somewhere within the second value?

Comment: Yes, but as my reply above, I can't have 1 match 01001 AND 00101, it can only match 0010x (x being variable).

Answer (score 0):

We decided to add a column to the table to make life easier for everyone.  So this question is no longer needed.  Thanks for you help.